# Is there a way to filter out questions from users who don't have a specific badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, questions-filter

I would like to only see questions which were asked by those who at least have the [Informed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188733#188733) badge. I don't like wasting my time answering (or even reading) questions by those who haven't bothered to read the rules. I suspect that spam would no longer be an issue either. Is this possible? Is it possible to make this the site default behavior for myself?

Comment: This isn't possible

Comment: Hmm. Requesting the [informed] badge is considerably less isolationist than most proposals along these lines. Downvote rescinded on reflection.

Comment: Had to check and make sure that I had mine!

Comment: Being able to search on badges could also have other uses, like filtering for authors with high rep on a tag.  For that matter, searching on other user characteristics could be useful, like users with rep of 1, or users who have been here for less than or more than some number of days, or user rep for specific tag.

Comment: @fixer1234 All of those things you mentioned with the exception of the request in the OP and the user rep for a specific tag are already available with the built-in search features. User rep by tag and filtering questions by user badge acquisition are both interesting things to implement but I don't know if the guys over at meta.SE would find it worth their time.

Comment: @allquixotic: The advanced search help mentions only a couple of user-related search abilities, and they relate to yourself.  Is there a reference to additional search parameters or could those be part of the 10K toolkit?

Comment: I guess, it is possible that this is a feature which has been considered and declined because of the impact it might have for self moderation of the site. IOW, if too many of the top users started filtering out in this way then those people will be even less likely to be helped. I personally think that this particular badge should be required before you use the site at all though.

Comment: What's wrong with being a bit elitist? I mean, if there's a way to filter questions by OP's rep and badges, then users writing useless RTFM-style answers and comments will be able to simply ignore questions from novice users.

Comment: I'd say a user doesn't have to have the badge on every site. The content of the tour page is practically identical on all stackexchange sites. Also if a user posts truly horrible questions, then you can just downvote and move on. In that case only a tiny number of users will ever have to see the question.

Comment: +1 for reading the tour on any, or one from a list of selected similar, SE sites (but that probably couldn't work as a normal filter).

Comment: It just occurred to me that this almost exists already.  On the main page, look at the answer count, rep, and badge count.  If there are zero answers, you're looking at just a question.  If there are answers, it's at least a "+" indication.  Q-only: if the poster has zero badges, they haven't taken the tour.  If they have any badges and 1 rep, there's a decent chance that they either took the tour or did something to get exposure to the site and are not totally clueless.  More than 1 rep means they have already done something right, which is a good indicator.  Not perfect, but a decent filter.

Comment: @fixer1234 Very good catch. In fact, this is enough to write a (server friendly) user mode script to handle the actual filtering.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Tampermonkey, here is one way to do it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Only Informed - Stack Exchange
// @namespace  http://example.com
// @version    0.1
// @description  Hides questions by users on Superuser.com who do not have any badges.
// @match      http://superuser.com/questions*
// ==/UserScript==

var questions = document.getElementById("questions"), userdetails, userdetailsCount, i, j;
for(i=0; i<questions.children.length; i++) {
    userdetails = questions.children[i].getElementsByClassName("user-details");
    for(j=0; j<userdetails.length; j++) {
        userdetailsCount = userdetails[j].children.length;
        if(userdetailsCount<4) questions.children[i].style.display = "none";
        // console.log(userdetailsCount);
    }
}
```

Not very well tested but it seems to work. May need to adjust the match condition more. It also doesn't handle questions which load in real time. It does show community posts though. It leaves the home page alone; it only affects the questions listed under "Questions".